# having some trouble with user input and output in haskell

Tags: haskell, io

Hi there I am just starting out with haskell and I have hit a block at a simple question involving input and output.
I am trying to ask the user a maths question , in this case: The user is asked what the result would be in adding the numbers 37 and 53 together. 
if they enter the correct answer (90) the program will print "excellent" and if they answer incorrectly it will print "sorry" 
I have managed to do this part.
What i dont understand how to do is to then show as output what the actual answer is, the users answer and finally the difference between the actual answer and the users answer

```
//the GHCI shell
it should show: 
*Main mathSkill
what is 37 + 53?
55
Sorry  
'' here is where i want it to show the rest of the info"
```

any help is greatly appreciated

```
--the haskell code
mathSkill = do
let answer = 90         
putStrLn "What is 37 + 53?"
result <- getLine
if (read result) /= answer
then putStrLn "Sorry"
else putStrLn "excellent"
```

Comment: Is that your actual indentation? Haskell is indentation aware, and it's best to use spaces for alignment.

Comment: Why do you use `snippets` for [tag:javascript] and [tag:html] as language indicator?

Comment: Sorry I couldnt find the Haskell language indicator

Answer (score 1):

@bheklilr has hit the nail on the head here: there is nothing wrong with your code except its indendation. If you want just a one-liner, the functions `(>>)` and `(>>=)` do the same thing as do-notation:

```
Prelude> putStrLn "What is 37 + 53?" >> getLine >>= \r -> if read r /= 90 then putStrLn "Sorry" else putStrLn "Excellent"
What is 37 + 53?
30
Sorry
```

This is equivalent to:

```
do { putStrLn "What is 37 + 53?"; r <- getLine; if read r /= 90 then putStrLn "Sorry" else putStrLn "Excellent" }
```

If you leave out those curly braces and semicolons, Haskell allows you do do something like Python but whitespace aware. To do multiline input in GHCi you will need to start with the `:{` and end with the `:}` special lines:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| do
Prelude|     putStrLn "What is 37 + 53?"
Prelude|     r <- getLine
Prelude|     if read r /= 90
Prelude|     then putStrLn "Sorry"
Prelude|     else putStrLn "Excellent"
Prelude| :}
What is 37 + 53?
50
Sorry
```

Haskell will automatically understand that those first two lines are supposed to stand on their own while the if/then/else is all one coherent construct.

Comment: The problem is not with what I have, Its what i dont have: I need to show once the program has given the string " sorry" to then give the actual answer 90 and the difference between the actual answer and the users result. Perhaps as a pair, answer difference (90,_)

Comment: Aha. So you'll need a string concatenation and a bunch of `show` functions: `let answer = 90` followed by `guess = read r` followed by `putStrLn $ "Sorry, the actual answer was: " ++ show answer ++ ", and you were off by " ++ show (abs (answer - guess)) ++ "."`